Shortest Edge Paths, using Position Distance to Empty not working with imported Alembic meshes
I have an alembic file that I've imported, created using an object and camera track from SynthEyes, that I am trying to use in a geonodes setup, with Shortest Edge Paths/Edge Paths To Curves.
The imported Alembic has an empty, which has transform and rotation values, as well as a transform constraint, that's linked to the imported alembic's file. The actual mesh, parented to the empty, also has transform and rotation values. None of this has been changed since importing the alembic file. Cylinder_AppliedTransforms.001 is named how it was imported, and I have not done any other transforms and then applied them. Below you can see currently-disabled geonodes setup, the transform cache/transforms for the parented empty, and the selected mesh's transforms. I'll post what happens with the geonodes enabled later.

This is a Working Example of the effect I am trying to achieve, using Shortest Edge Paths on the mesh the geonodes is setup on, with the start and end points controlled with the position of two empties.

This is what happens when the geonodes is enabled, no visible output:

Using a viewer node for the Start Empty connected to the Position-Distance-Equal-to-Zero Compare, shows that all of the points are showing as "True," compared to the WorkingExample which I have screenshot on the left:

What I have tried so far:

Parenting a test icosphere to another object that is transformed. Setup new geonodes and recreate. Works as intended.
Inside of blender, animating a small section of an empty's rotation and translation with a mesh parented to it, selected the hierarchy, exported the animation as an alembic. Deleted entire setup and re-imported. Works as intended.
Exporting an FBX from SynthEyes, and importing to blender, recreated geonodes setup. Same result as Non-working alembic setup.
I've also tried a setup using Sample Nearest/Sample Index, but I'm not confident I've set that up correctly, and I also know I'm going to be performing the setup on the input geometry anyway, so doing that seems extraneous since the mesh data will be there as the geometry input in the first place.

I'd like to know if there's some glaring oversight I've missed, or some such, before I go through doing a new camera and object track just to test with some other mesh/data, etc.
Using blender's matchmove solver is a non-option, as there's no way to get Blender's minimum required points for this camera and object track (plus, I've already done the work elsewhere so redoing it seems less than useful).
